# How to recover root for system?

Tags: data-recovery

I have accidentally executed

```
rm -rf /.
```

How to recover the / file system. Is there any way to recover the root file system.

Comment: yes, from backups

Comment: use `rm -rfvI {file}` next time. You will at least get a chance to say goodbye to your file system. ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you have an enterprise backup system, you can do a bare metal restore. Otherwise, no.

Comment: What do you mean with an "enterprise" backup system?

Comment: As in, not something you've personally put together that rsync's the `DocumentRoot` for apache somewhere off-host. Enterprise backup systems typically have a Live CD environment you boot into which finds your local installation, contacts the media server and pulls down the entire OS from the latest backup.

Comment: SyncSort, Tivoli, NetBackup, etc are example of commercial enterprise backup systems. Not sure if there are any FOSS ones though since there's usually a lot of moving parts.

Comment: It looks like [Amanda can do a BMR](http://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/How_To:Do_a_Bare_Metal_Restore) never used Amanda, though.